# Aptana Studio 3 node.js mandatoryprerequisite error

Tags: node.js, installation, aptana, aptana3, failed-installation

I have downloaded Aptana Studio 3 stand alone version for a fresh installation. However, every time I am trying to install, it gets stuck in the same error:

> `"couldn't find mandatory prerequisites.`

I have already installed the latest version of node.js, please help.. :(

I have added the following screenshots for better understanding:

- [This the first screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iWhP.png)
- [downloading softwares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjGtS.png)
- [Already have latest node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuMXe.png)
- [this is next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aabSs.png)
- [this is where it gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdBkC.png)
- [:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDz5L.png)